# How to deploy new CA certificate to Firefox installs

Tags: windows, domain, firefox, deployment

Is there a way do deploy remotely new CA certificates to Firefox installs?

In other words, has anything changed since this question was answered [Installing a CA certificate on multiple Windows machines (IE/Firefox)](https://serverfault.com/questions/77232/installing-a-ca-certificate-on-multiple-windows-machines-ie-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `certutil` from NSS Tools [1] you can administer the certificate databases used by softwares like Firefox and Thunderbird [2]:

```
certutil.exe -A -n <cert name> -t <trust> -i <cert filepath> -d <firefox/thunderbird profile dirpath)
```

Example that adds "mycompany.pem" certificate file as "mycompany" into Firefox profile and set to trusts it as a CA that can issue client certificates for SSL, e-mail and signing (`_C,C,C`) as well as server certificates for SSL (`T_,_,_`).
Should be done when software is not running.

```
certutil.exe -A -n "mycompany" -t "CT,C,C" -i "mycompany.pem" -d "C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\someprofile.abcdef"

# Remote profile accessed via administrative share
certutil.exe -A -n "mycompany" -t "CT,C,C" -i "mycompany.pem" -d "\\computer\c$\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\someprofile.abcdef"
```

You could also run the first command via [PsTools's `PsExec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx).

NSS Tools sources can be grabbed from https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/security/nss/releases/ (some Windows binaries can be found on the Internet but given the security nature: it's better to compile it yourself)

[1]: Network Security Services: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/NSS/tools/NSS_Tools_certutil

[2]: They are using a *Netscape Communicator database* with files `cert8.db` and `key3.db`.